# PyODBC Iterating Update - "Not a Query"

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, pyodbc

I am working to pull a Customer Service ticket's verbiage ("Note") from a SQL Server 2008 R2 table, then run a sentiment analysis and use that analysis to update the "Sentiment" field within the same table. Here's more info on the table fields:

```
TicketNoteID(PK, int, not null)
TicketID (FK, int, not null)
UserName (varchar(20), not null)
Note (varchar(max), not null)
Author (varchar(50), not null)
isExternal (bit, null)
DateTimeCreated (datetime, not null)
NoteID (int, null)
DateTimeUploaded (datetime, null)
Error (bit, null)
ErrorMessage (varchar(max), null)
Sentiment (float, null)
```

When I run the below code, I get this error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

I've modeled my code after other posts about this same error, but I'm unable to find anything that will resolve the issue. Here's the code:

```
import pyodbc
from textblob import TextBlob

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=...')

cur = cnxn.cursor()

sql = """
    SELECT Note
    FROM dbo.DSDTicketNotes
    where Sentiment is NULL
"""
rows = cur.execute(sql)

for row in rows:
    note = cur.fetchone()
    row = str(note)
    blob = TextBlob(row)
    sent = blob.sentiment.polarity
    sentUpdate = cur.execute("UPDATE dbo.DSDTicketNotes SET Sentiment = ?", sent)

cur.close()
cnxn.close()
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: `UPDATE` statement looks like it needs a `WHERE` clause, otherwise it's updating all rows for each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to simultaneously iterate through cursor results *and* use the **same** cursor to execute other statements.

If the requirement is to iterate through the `SELECT` results one by one (e.g. results too large to fit in memory) and take action, manage two cursors:

```
...
selectCur = cnxn.cursor()
updateCur = cnxn.cursor()

selectSQL = """
    SELECT TicketNoteID, Note
    FROM dbo.DSDTicketNotes
    where Sentiment is NULL
"""

updateSQL = """
    UPDATE dbo.DSDTicketNotes
    SET Sentiment = ?
    WHERE TicketNoteID = ?
"""

for row in selCur.execute(selectSQL):
    id = row[0]
    blob = TextBlob(str(row[1]))
    sent = blob.sentiment.polarity
    updateCur = updateCur.execute(updateSQL, (sent, id))
    updateCur.commit()
...
```

Or if the `SELECT` resultset will **always** be small, pull the results into a list for iteration. This allows cursor reuse:

```
...
cur = cnxn.cursor()

selectSQL = """
    SELECT TicketNoteID, Note
    FROM dbo.DSDTicketNotes
    where Sentiment is NULL
"""

updateSQL = """
    UPDATE dbo.DSDTicketNotes
    SET Sentiment = ?
    WHERE TicketNoteID = ?
"""

rows = cur.execute(selectSQL).fetchall()
for row in rows:
    id = row[0]
    blob = TextBlob(str(row[1]))
    sent = blob.sentiment.polarity
    cur = cur.execute(updateSQL, (sent, id))
    cur.commit()
...
```

Regardless of the method used, you'll want to include the primary key in the `SELECT` so it can be used to `UPDATE` the specific row being processed.

Comment: Bryan, this is great. Thanks for sending. That said, it get's us most of the way, but the update query is updating all rows with the sentiment from the first record. I tried to throw in a counter and use row[a], but that didn't work...

Comment: What's the primary key for the table? Better yet, edit the question with DDL for the table.

Comment: Bryan, I've added the requested info. Thanks!